# How do you make unallocated space in OS X El Capitan?

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, macos

I'm trying to install Windows 10 on my Macbook Pro, but Windows won't let me format the Bootcamp created disk. I've seen people make unallocated space on their drive to install Windows on. Unfortunately, El Capitan won't let me make unallocated space. Any tips?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure how to solve the problem, but I can give you an important first step: **back up everything important on the computer**. It's easy to mess up and reformat the Mac partition from Windows, and if that happens everything will be gone... unless you have a backup copy. Time Machine is great, or if you know what files are important you can copy them off by hand. But do *something*.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?